# ClientError: Saved entry is empty when using aws import-image command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I am trying to import an image into AMI in AWS. The VM has been tried over a .ova & .vmdk.

I get through the statuses of Converting, Updating, then I get the message on **ClientError: Saved entry is empty**. Tried googling around but to no avail. Any help on what this means?

*aws ec2 import-image --description "HCPVM" --disk-containers "file://C:\hhh\containers2.json"*

```
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Status": "deleted",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "hhh-em",
                        "S3Key": "hhh-VM-VMDK-disk1.vmdk"
                    },
                    "DiskImageSize": 1020535808.0,
                    "Description": "First disk",
                    "Format": "VMDK"
                },
                {
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "hhh-em",
                        "S3Key": "hhh-VM-VMDK-disk2.vmdk"
                    },
                    "DiskImageSize": 132096.0,
                    "Description": "Second disk",
                    "Format": "VMDK"
                },
                {
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "hhh-em",
                        "S3Key": "hhh-VM-VMDK-disk3.vmdk"
                    },
                    "DiskImageSize": 132096.0,
                    "Description": "Third disk",
                    "Format": "VMDK"
                }
            ],
            "Description": "hhhVM",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Saved entry is empty",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-fg7xdq2r"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you add `--debug --verbose` to the command to see if you get additional info

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that AWS is passing back from your newly created instance right after it boots.

Most likely, there's a grub configuration problem.  In my case, I had grub set to change the default entry by the last selected.  Change default in grub/menu.lst to 0 and try again--but you're at the point where you need to look at what is inside your image more closely.